# Spring boot HeaderWriterFilter overrides header created in controller

Tags: spring, controller, header

When I add a header to the responseEntity in the Controller, it is not added to the response. I debug the code, an when it reach the "HeaderWriterFilter" it adds default header, but it has no track of the one added in the Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/get-file",
        method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> download(Principal principal, Long fileId) throws IOException {
    if (principal == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }

    try {
        User loggedInUser = ((LoggedInUserDetails) ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) principal).getPrincipal()).getLoggedInUser();

//            Get file
        File file = this.fileService.getById(loggedInUser, fileId);
        if (file == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
        }

//            Get file for download
        java.io.File physicalFile = new java.io.File(file.getUrl());
        if (file == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(null);
        }
        InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(physicalFile));

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("test", "test.yaml");

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(headers)
        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
        .contentLength(physicalFile.length())
        .body(resource);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `HeaderWriterFilter` is for writing additional security headers, it doesn't do anything with the `HttpHeaders` from the controllers. It only adds if headers aren't there they won't be added. Basically it should already be there, if it isn't something isn't right in your response. Show your full controller method (not just the snippet).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated it with the full controller. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Although some things could be improved nothing really wrong with it. I assume you are using an `@RestController` and not an `@Controller` here. You are using streaming so it might be something in the result handling in Spring itself (not Spring Security which is what the `HeaderWriterFilter` is part of, I'm pretty sure of that as I wrote that class :) ).

Comment: Yes, sorry that was my mistake supposing it because it was the only place where I saw any header appearing. Do you know who can I ask for information to solve this issue? Thank you again

Comment: Enable debug logging and you might want to check/debug the `HttpEntityMethodProcessor`. The headers are written after the body (afaik) so that might be why you don't see them at first while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a missing header in WebSecurityConfig. I solved the problem adding

```
configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("fileName"));
```

in CorsConfigurationSource.